# how to use field value as condition in sql server query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am creating Questionnaire dynamically with the relations between questions.

It means one question should be shown or hidden depends upon the other question's answer.

I have created 2 tables one for questions and one for relation ships.

Now in the relationship table i have values like this :

```
ParentQuesId         ChildQuesId         Operand         Answer
    35                   45                =              yes
    35                   46                =              no   
    37                   52               >=              10
```

question 35 has 2 options yes and no.  now when user selects yes then question 45 should be shown and 46 should be hidden and when user selects no then question 46 should be shown and 45 should be hidden.

and same for question 37 when the user choose answer greater or equals to 10 question 52 should be shown.

Now i am making sql query based on ParentQuesId and user's answer.

But i don't know how can i make condition based on the operand, answer and user answer's value.

what i have tried so far is as below :

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(255)
 declare @parent int = 35
 declare @userans nvarchar(100) = 'yes'
 set @sql = 'select * from QuesRelations where ParentQuesId = '+ cast(@parent as nvarchar(50)) +' and '''+ cast(@userans as nvarchar(50)) +''' = Answer';
 exec(@sql)
```

But i need to make this 2nd condition [ i.e @userans + Operand + Answer ]  dynamic which is based upon the operand field value

Can anyone help me please to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you do this just as regular SQL:

```
select *
from QuesRelations
where ParentQuesId = @parent and
      ((operand = '=' and @answer = answer) or
       (operand = '>=' and @answer >= answer)
      );
```

You can of course extend the `where` to handle other operands, such as:

```
select *
from QuesRelations
where ParentQuesId = @parent and
      ((operand = '=' and @answer = answer) or
       (operand = '>=' and @answer >= answer)
       (operand = '>' and @answer > answer)
       (operand = '<=' and @answer <= answer)
       (operand = '<' and @answer < answer)
      );
```

Comment: Thanks gordon for your reply but operand is not fixed. I need to use the operand and answer as condition.

Comment: @Mausami . . . Just expand the `where` to include all the possible operands.